# Meaning of "Query From Hell"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm reading [Scaling Out SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479364.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and came across with this in the article. I googled it and not enough answers. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Performance impacting query (most likely)

Comment: "When someone tries to run a garbage query that hogs up all of the resources (query from hell) it only affects one of the engines"

Comment: But might also be: https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/2265/the-sql-query-from-hell-or-the-horror-the-horror :p

Comment: @RC. That is the query from hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU bound query.
A SQL Server instance can process a single query for hours without any effect on the whole system, because there are still 7 other SQL Server instances free to process other queries.

This is not true for IO bound query, since the 8 SQL Server instances are using a shared disk.

Comment: No. The CPU intensive  query is the query from hell since It would have a huge impact on a single machine but not on a cluster. An  I/O intensive query would have effect on both architectures and of course there can be one. Reading is also a I/O operation and "most of the data is cached" is a very bold statement.

Answer (score 0):

From the preceding sentence in that article:

> a query that ties up all the database resources for hours.

Comment: That "resource" might mean the db engines too. That's what confused my mind actually. It doesn't have to mean joining 30 entities in a select query.. I guess? :) Trying to understand it's meaning from the paragraph caused some ambiguous thoughts in my mind.. And they put it there like everyone knows it - "query from hell" :)